# Binomial Probability (Dice)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, dice

The throwing of a one or two is called a success. The six dice are thrown together 64 times and the frequencies of the throws with 0, 1, 2,..., 6 successes are summed over all six pairs are as follows:

Success:      0    1    2    3     4    5   6 
Frequency:    0    4   19    15   17    7   2

(a)What would be the theoretical probability of success and the mean and variance of the above frequency distribution is all the dice were fair?

My friend and I got different answers. I multiplied by the successes from 0,..6, and my friend multiplied by the frequencies.

Who is correct?
[image]
[image]

(c) Test the hypothesis that the mean and variance have their theoretical mean?

What kind of test would you suggest? 2-sample binomial test and we can approx with Z? And what kind of test for variance? Chi-sqaured?

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely correct to multiply the number of successes by their probabilities for E(X).

The result (2) should be intuitive since since you have a 1/3 chance on any given die roll and 6 dice.  However, if you do this 64 times, you should multiply your results by 64 as well (i.e. 128 is the expected successes for 64 sets of 6 dice - 384 total rolls).

Here is a link on confidence intervals for binomial distributions - there are several options:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals